# europasscv how to add a second address (eventually with icon)

Tags: addresses, europasscv

I would like to add a second address line to personal info of europasscv template, if possible with the same logo of the first one. Which would be the better solution?

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}
\ecvname{name }
\ecvaddress{addressone}
\ecvtelephone{000 00000000}
\ecvemail{a@gmail.com}
\ecvdateofbirth{00 00 00 }
\ecvnationality{xxxx}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

  \ecvpersonalinfo
  \ecvsection{Section}

  \ecvtitle{Novembre 2018 -- Present}{xxxxxxx - }
  \ecvitem{}{where xxxx}
  \ecvitem{}{XXXXXXX}


  \end{europasscv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can copy the part out of class `europasscv.cls` where the icon is added to the address and can use it in the command like:

```
\ecvaddress{%
  addressone\\% <=========================================== first address
  \raisebox{-2\lineskip}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{address_europass_icon.pdf}% <=========
  }\hspace{0.2mm}
  addresstwo% <============================================ second address
}
```

That code adds an second address in a separate line and adds the same icon (`address_europass_icon.pdf`) used for the first address to the CV.

Please see the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{europasscv}
\ecvname{name }
\ecvaddress{%
  addressone\\%
  \raisebox{-2\lineskip}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{address_europass_icon.pdf}% <=========
  }\hspace{0.2mm}
  addresstwo%
}
\ecvtelephone{000 00000000}
\ecvemail{a@gmail.com}
\ecvdateofbirth{00 00 00 }
\ecvnationality{xxxx}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

  \ecvpersonalinfo
  \ecvsection{Section}

  \ecvtitle{Novembre 2018 -- Present}{xxxxxxx - }
  \ecvitem{}{where xxxx}
  \ecvitem{}{XXXXXXX}


\end{europasscv}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting cv]